# How to get key from map

Tags: go, go-templates, consul-template

I'm working on go template. Having some map in `.` I know how to get the value, as long as I know the key.

```
"Map value: {{ printf "%s" .key1 }}"
```

How to get key name from inside the template? I would expect maybe something like

```
"Map key: {{ printf "%s" (keys .)[0] }}"
```

Comment: You can `range` over a map to get *all* the keys and values, is that what you're looking for? There's no meaningful way to get a slice of the keys you can access by numeric index because slices are ordered and maps are not.

Comment: @Adrian yes, sounds like what I need.

Comment: `range` is covered in the documentation under Actions: https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions

Comment: @Adrian Thanks, I can see it and it works indeed. Just don't want to put an answer when it is you who actually gave it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Adrian commented:

```
{{ range $key, $val := . }}
key: {{ $key }}; value: {{ $val }}
{{ end }}
```

But it was hard to figure it out just from [range documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions)

Comment: WindyFields may be the answer to the title, but this is the technique I would actually use in a template.

Comment: This saves my life. THANKS !

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged with `consul-template`... the syntax for Consul/Vault templates is (given `.Data` is the map):

```
{{ index .Data "complex.key.name" }}
```

This is useful, when the the key name is complex (say contains dots) and `{{ .Data.complex.key.name }}` is interpreted as accessing nested fields.